# How do I create a virtual machine on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, virtualization

I'd like to create a virtual machine running on Windows 7. On Windows XP / Vista I have been using either Microsoft Virtual PC or VMware Workstation. I believe I heard somewhere that virtualization is part of Windows 7.

How can I create a virtual machine?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you heard of is known as **[XP Mode for Windows 7](http://news.cnet.com/8301-13860_3-10229125-56.html)**, which is basically a Microsoft VirtualPC image (free for licensees of Windows 7 Professional and Ultimate) to run Windows XP applications within Windows 7.

Other than that, you can still use your virtualizer of choice (e.g. **[VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/)**, [**Microsoft VPC**](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/) or [**VMware**](http://www.vmware.com/)) and create your own virtual machine.

Comment: Thank you fro pointing me to the right direction. One small correction:
"Windows XP Mode Release Candidate (RC) and Windows Virtual PC RC, available on Windows 7 Professional and Windows 7 Ultimate". I just found this info here http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/default.aspx .  +1 for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: duly noted and corrected :)

Answer (score 2):

I've installed [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) on Windows 7 for this purpose and it works great.

You can still install the latest version of [Microsoft Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/) on other versions of Windows 7 but unless you have Ultimate or Enterprise you'll need to have a valid license for installing the guest OS as these versions include a specially licensed copy of Windows XP. If you're not interested in Windows XP then it doesn't really matter.